# Пунктуация у Аврелия Августина, хоть и Блаженного, но всё ж переводного

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

> Каким же образом уменьшается или исчезает будущее, которого ещё нет?
>   Каким образом растёт прошлое, которого уже нет? **Только потому, что
>   это происходит в душе, и только в ней существует три времени.** Она и
>   ждёт, и внимает, и помнит: то, чего она ждёт, проходит через то, чему
>   она внимает, и уходит туда, о чём она вспоминает. Кто станет отрицать,
>   что будущего ещё нет? Но в душе есть ожидание будущего. И кто станет
>   отрицать, что прошлого уже нет? Но и до сих пор есть в душе память о
>   прошлом. **И кто станет отрицать, что настоящее лишено длительности: оно
>   проходит мгновенно.** Наше внимание, однако, длительно, и оно переводит
>   в небытие то, что появится. Длительно не будущее время - его нет;
>   длительное будущее - это длительное ожидание будущего. Длительно не
>   прошлое, которого нет; длительное прошлое - это длительная память о
>   прошлом.

Боже, как многословен...

Интересуюсь запятой перед "и только".

*И кто станет отрицать, что настоящее лишено длительности: оно проходит мгновенно.* - Почему предложение не симметрично построено по отношению к своим двойникам? Почему не вопросительное?

Comment: Видимо, запятой закрывается придаточное. Но всё равно предложение кривое, на мой взгляд. Может, я тупой для понимания этого текста, но странно, что на вопрос "каким образом" отвечают "потому что". Если не этим, всё равно не понятно, что служит ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) ***Только потому, что это происходит в душе, и только в ней существует три времени.***

Придаточные при постановке запятой не считаются соподчиненными. Такая пунктуация и грамматика может быть связана с частицей ***только***, которая повторяется дважды, то есть последнее предложение с этой частицей считается самостоятельным.

2) Последнее предложение я бы составила так: ***(1) И кто станет отрицать, что (2) настоящее лишено длительности, что (3) оно проходит мгновенно?***

**Двоеточие здесь не подойдет**, оно делит сложное предложение на две части, в то время как здесь по смыслу **два однородных придаточных** (2) и (3), отнесенных к предложению (1).

3) **А с отрицанием мне всё БЫЛО неясно.**

Я думала так. Например: ***Кто станет отрицать, что будущего ещё нет?***  (Значит, этот кто-то утверждает, что будущее уже есть). Но ведь это авторская точка зрения.

В то же время автор вроде бы ведет полемику с невидимым собеседником. Тогда бы надо сказать так: Вы **утверждаете**, что будущего еще нет? Нет, вы неправы. Будущее есть в душе, это ожидание будущего.

Короче говоря, совсем запутал меня Августин своей риторикой.

4) **А ТЕПЕРЬ мне все объяснили.**

***КтО*** станет отрицать, что будущего ещё нет. **Нет таких отрицающих,** так как **все считают, что его действительно нет.** Августин излагает точку зрения большинства, которую он считает неправильной.

Comment: ***Кто станет отрицать, что будущего ещё нет?** (Значит, этот кто-то утверждает, что будущее уже есть).* — Нет, наоборот: это означает, что с точки зрения автора все согласятся, что будущего ещё нет. С остальным согласен.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я, конечно, понимала, что у Августина всё правильно, но смысл фразы был неясен. Но я очень надеялась, что кто-нибудь меня поправит, чтобы мы с ним ( с Августином) были заодно.

Comment: Ах, мой милый Аугустин... То ж переводчикова-редакторова работа. Но скока многа слов!.. Удавиться.